# code generation in setup.py

Tags: python

I've got some XML files from which I intend to derive some python source code; they are things like lists of language codes. Does the distribute module have a hook I can plug into for this purpose? To be perhaps clearer, I don't want to ship XML around. I want to only ship .py files. I want to derive some .py files by running a program that generates them from XML.

Comment: Do you want the conversion to be done when the module is loaded or are you planning on doing it some time beforehand in a different step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [create a custom distutils](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1712544/11265) command for your code gen process, or you can [override build itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11332078/11265). This would require you to include the XML, though.

I'd probably move the code generation into my local build process, using [zc.buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) with a templating recipe like [z3c.recipe.template](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.recipe.template). The XML would then be part of the development build, with only the code generated Python files included in the user distribution.