# How do I subclass the build command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

The subject is self-descriptive: I need to subclass the `setup.py build` command in order to perform additional build steps. However I've failed to find any `build` command class to inherit from. I've been trying:

```
class BuildCommandProxy(setuptools.command.build):
    pass
```

and

```
class BuildCommandProxy(distutils.command.build):
    pass
```

and even:

```
class BuildCommandProxy(setuptools.distutils.command.build):
    pass
```

without any success.

**UPDATE**: looking for how to implement something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11332078/359730) with `setuptools`.

**UPDATE2**: I have some custom command implementation:

```
class CustomCommand(setuptools.Command):
    # ...
```

What I would like to implement is to pass this command to `cmdclass` like this:

```
cmdclass={
    "build": CustomCommand,
}
```

and then invoke the original `build` in `CustomCommand.run` after doing some custom steps.

Comment: Are you passing `cmdclass` to `setup()`?  Please post relevant parts of `setup.py`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Setuptools does not override the `distutils` `build` command itself; only the `build_py` and `build_ext` subcommands.

So, to create your own subclass you need to import from the `distutils.command.build` *module*, which contains a `build` class (subclass of `Command`):

```
import distutils.command.build

class BuildCommandProxy(distutils.command.build.build):
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, here is a full example of how to add custom build operations:

```
import distutils.command.build

# Override build command
class BuildCommand(distutils.command.build.build):

    def run(self):
        # Run the original build command
        distutils.command.build.build.run(self)
        # Custom build stuff goes here

# Replace the build command with ours
setup(...,
      cmdclass={"build": BuildCommand})
```