# Run Makefile on pip install

Tags: python, makefile, pip

I have some protocol buffer definitions which need to be built to Python source as part of the `pip install` process. I've subclassed the `setuptools.command.install` command in `setup.py` but I think it's trying to run the Makefile after the package is installed so the sources aren't recognised.

I can't find information about what happens during a pip installation. Can anyone shed any light?

setup.py:

```
import subprocess
import sys

from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install

class Install(install):
    """Customized setuptools install command - builds protos on install."""
    def run(self):
        protoc_command = ["make", "python"]
        if subprocess.call(protoc_command) != 0:
            sys.exit(-1)
        install.run(self)


setup(
    name='myprotos',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='Protocol Buffers.',
    install_requires=[],
    cmdclass={
        'install': Install,
    }
)
```

Output of `$ pip install -vvv .`:

```
Processing /path/to/myprotos
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/3t/4qwkfyr903d0b7db7by2kj6r0000gn/T/pip-jpgCby-build/setup.py) egg_info for package from file:///path/to/myprotos
    Running command python setup.py egg_info
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/myprotos.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/myprotos.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/myprotos.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/myprotos.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/myprotos.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/myprotos.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/myprotos.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Source in /private/var/folders/3t/4qwkfyr903d0b7db7by2kj6r0000gn/T/pip-jpgCby-build has version 0.0.1, which satisfies requirement myprotos==0.0.1 from file:///path/to/myprotos
Building wheels for collected packages: myprotos
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for myprotos: started
  Destination directory: /var/folders/3t/4qwkfyr903d0b7db7by2kj6r0000gn/T/tmpD7dfGKpip-wheel-
  Running command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/3t/4qwkfyr903d0b7db7by2kj6r0000gn/T/pip-jpgCby-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /var/folders/3t/4qwkfyr903d0b7db7by2kj6r0000gn/T/tmpD7dfGKpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  installing to build/bdist.macosx-10.12-x86_64/wheel
  running install

  # THIS IS MY MAKEFILE RUNNING
  Grabbing github.com/google/protobuf...
  Building Python protos...
  # MAKEFILE COMPLETE

  running install_egg_info
  running egg_info
  creating myprotos.egg-info
  writing myprotos.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing top-level names to myprotos.egg-info/top_level.txt
  writing dependency_links to myprotos.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing manifest file 'myprotos.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest file 'myprotos.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  writing manifest file 'myprotos.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Copying myprotos.egg-info to build/bdist.macosx-10.12-x86_64/wheel/myprotos-0.0.1-py2.7.egg-info
  running install_scripts
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.12-x86_64/wheel/myprotos-0.0.1.dist-info/WHEEL
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for myprotos: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /Users/jds/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/92/0b/37/b5a50146994bc0b6774407139f01d648ba3a9b4853d2719c51
  Removing source in /private/var/folders/3t/4qwkfyr903d0b7db7by2kj6r0000gn/T/pip-jpgCby-build
Successfully built myprotos
Installing collected packages: myprotos
  Found existing installation: myprotos 0.0.1
    Uninstalling myprotos-0.0.1:
      Removing file or directory /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myprotos-0.0.1.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
      Removing file or directory /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myprotos-0.0.1.dist-info/INSTALLER
      Removing file or directory /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myprotos-0.0.1.dist-info/METADATA
      Removing file or directory /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myprotos-0.0.1.dist-info/RECORD
      Removing file or directory /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myprotos-0.0.1.dist-info/WHEEL
      Removing file or directory /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myprotos-0.0.1.dist-info/metadata.json
      Removing file or directory /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myprotos-0.0.1.dist-info/top_level.txt
      Successfully uninstalled myprotos-0.0.1

Successfully installed myprotos-0.0.1
Cleaning up...
```

Should my Makefile be running early in the process to generate the source files? Do the files need to be there before `egg_info` runs for example?

If I manually run the Makefile and then install the package then it works.

---

#### Update

Here is the structure of my project:

```
myprotos
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── document.proto
├── myprotos         # Generated by Makefile
│   ├── __init__.py  # Generated by Makefile
│   └── proto_pb2.py # Generated by Makefile
└── setup.py
```

Here is the section of the Makefile which generates the Python source from Potocol Buffer definitions:

```
python: protoc deps
    # the protoc and deps command above just downloads
    # the `protoc` binary to a local bin directory 
    @echo "Building Python protos..."
    @mkdir -p "${PYTHON_OUT}"
    @touch "${PYTHON_OUT}"/__init__.py
    @printf "__all__ = ['proto_pb2']" > "${PYTHON_OUT}"/__init__.py
    @PATH="${LOCAL_BINARY_PATH}:$$PATH" protoc \
        --proto_path="${BASE}" \
        --proto_path="${GOPATH}/src/github.com/google/protobuf/src" \
        --python_out="${PYTHON_OUT}/" \
        ${PROTOS}
```

Comment: You should run it [on build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14644982/636626), not on install

Comment: @NilsWerner I've updated `setup.py` to subclass the build command but I still have problems importing the package. There seems to be no sources in the wheel that's built.

Comment: What does your [`MANIFEST.in`](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#manifest-template) look like? Also, your `Makefile` generates source files that should go in the `sdist`?

Comment: @NilsWerner I don't have a `MANIFEST.in` file. However, if I run `make` and then `pip install .` then the package is installed and useable. It seems that even in `build` the Python source isn't being generated early enough.

Comment: yes, that's expected. You need to add all non-py source files to `MANIFEST.in` and amend your question with what exactly your `Makefile` does and what files it consumes and generates. Because if it generates source files, it needs to go in the `sdist` command, if it compiles existing source files it needs to go in the `build` section.

Comment: @NilsWerner ok right. Please see my update for the project structure and the makefile.

Comment: OK, I would say you need to run `make` in `build`, add `Makefile` and `doctument.proto` to `MANIFEST.in` (so they end up in the `sdist`), and add a field `packages=['myprotos']` to `setup()`.

Comment: GENIUS! Good work @NilsWerner, makes perfect sense. I just needed to ensure the `myprotos` module directory is created before `egg_info` runs, otherwise it fails. Do you want to try and put together an answer so I can give you those wholesome internet points?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, there are three things you need to change here:

1. Add `Makefile` and `document.proto` to a new file `MANIFEST.in`.

   ```
    Makefile
    document.proto
   ```

   If you do that, the `.zip` file created by `python setup.py sdist` (which is also uploaded to PyPI) will contain those files.
2. You need to run your `make` command during `python setup.py build`, not during `install`. Since you are **generating Python code**, you will need to change the `build_py` command here:

   ```
    import sys
    import subprocess

    from setuptools import setup
    from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py

    class Build(build_py):
        """Customized setuptools build command - builds protos on build."""
        def run(self):
            protoc_command = ["make", "python"]
            if subprocess.call(protoc_command) != 0:
                sys.exit(-1)
            super().run()


    setup(
        name='buildtest',
        version='1.0',
        description='Python Distribution Utilities',
        packages=['buildtest'],
        cmdclass={
            'build_py': Build,
        }
    )
   ```

   If your `Makefile` **generated machine code**, i.e. from C or any other compiled language, you should change the `build_ext` command:

   ```
    import sys
    import subprocess

    from setuptools import setup
    from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext

    class Build(build_ext):
        """Customized setuptools build command - builds protos on build."""
        def run(self):
            protoc_command = ["make", "python"]
            if subprocess.call(protoc_command) != 0:
                sys.exit(-1)
            super().run()


    setup(
        name='buildtest',
        version='1.0',
        description='Python Distribution Utilities',
        packages=['buildtest'],
        has_ext_modules=lambda: True,
        cmdclass={
            'build_ext': Build,
        }
    )
   ```
3. Lastly, you need to tell `setuptools` to install the resulting package on `install` by defining an attribute `packages` in `setup()`:

   ```
    setup(
        ...
        packages=['myprotos']
    )
   ```

The reason for deciding to run `build_py` or `build_ext` lies in the situation when the two are run:

- `build_py` is also run when creating source distributions, which have to be cross-platform. Compiled extensions are usually not cross-platform, so you cannot compile them in this step.
- `build_ext` is only run when you are creating binary distributions, which are platform-specific. It is OK to compile to platform-specific machine code here.

Comment: `build` does not appear to exist in recent `setuptools.command`. `build_py` seems to work.

Comment: @Nils: it works but some how package files are not copied only distribution files are there after pip install