# Compile C library on pip install

Tags: python, pip, ctypes

I made a Python application which needs to execute C functions. To do so, I compiled the C functions in a shared library using gcc and called the library in my Python script using ctypes.

I'm trying to pack my application in a pip package but found no way to create the shared library upon pip install.

I tried the following (setup.py) :

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install
import subprocess

class compileLibrary(install):
    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        command = "cd packageName"
        command += " && git clone https://mygit.com/myAwesomeCLibrary.git"
        command += " && gcc -my -many -options"
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
    process.wait()

setup(
    name='packageName',
    version='0.1',
    packages=['packageName'],
    install_requires=[
        ...
    ],
cmdclass={'install': compileLibrary},
```

)

This works when doing `python setup.py install` but, when installing from pip, while the install process is successful, the shared library is not in the package folder (`pythonx.x/site-packages/packageName`).

I tried using distutils with the same result.

Based on the question [Run Makefile on pip install](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45347685/4187028) I also tried the following setup.py :

```
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.command.build import build
import subprocess


class Build(build):
    def run(self):
        command = "cd packageName"
        command += " && git clone https://mygit.com/myAwesomeCLibrary.git"
        command += " && gcc -my -many -options"
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
        process.wait()
        build.run(self)


setup(
    name='packageName',
    version='0.1',
    packages=['packageName'],
    install_requires=[
        ...
    ],
    cmdclass={'build': Build},
)
```

Here is the architecture of my package

```
packageName/
├── packageName/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── myFunctions.c
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.md
├── setup.py
```

Note : After installing the package with pip, I only have `__init__.py` and `__pycache__` in the install folder (`pythonx.x/site-packages/packageName`).

How can I create the shared library during pip install so It can be used by my package ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After hours of research, I found the solution. The main problems were :

- Use `Extension` from `setuptools` to compile the library
- Use a custom install function to `git clone` and calling the constructor **at the end** so the `git clone` occurs before the compilation.

Here is the working `setup.py` :

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from setuptools.command.install import install
import subprocess
import os

class CustomInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        command = "git clone https://mygit.com/myAwesomeCLibrary.git"
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, cwd="packageName")
        process.wait()
        install.run(self)

module = Extension('packageName.library',
                   sources = ['packageName/library.c'],
                   include_dirs = ['packageName/include'],
                   extra_compile_args=['-fPIC'])

setup(
    name='packageName',
    version='0.1',
    packages=['packageName'],
    install_requires=[
        ...
    ],
    cmdclass={'install': CustomInstall},
    include_package_data=True,
    ext_modules=[module],
)
```

Comment: When trying to use this with `python -m build`, I'm finding that this errors with a "file not found" when trying to compile the C files. After some experimentation, it seems the `CustomInstall` section runs *after* the module compilation instead of before (which obviously doesn't work).

Answer (score -1):

you can add the shared library in MANIFEST.in.
like this:

`include *.so *.dylib`

Comment: Thank you but I want to compile the library during the pip install.

Comment: So you want to using the CustomInstall not the CustomBuild.