# Create pip-installable package with C extension pulled from Github

Tags: python, c, setuptools, python-packaging, python-extensions

I have a python library that I'm trying to package into something pip-installable. It depends upon a C library ([shoco](https://github.com/Ed-von-Schleck/shoco)). I'd like to avoid packaging the actual source code to shoco in my own package if possible.

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47360113/compile-c-library-on-pip-install), but it seems this does not work with modern Python packaging (i.e. via `python -m build`). In particular, the pre-install script seems not to run until after the installation is complete, and as a result `gcc` fails because the C files to compile aren't there yet.

Is there a reasonable way of including "git clone this repo then compile it" into the pip-install process for a package? I'd like to avoid copying the shoco source code directly into my source tree if possible.

Comment: Maybe the job is already done and you can depend on it: https://pypi.org/project/pyshoco/

Comment: That would have been a lot more convenient, but unfortunately the package segfaults in my experimentation. As such, I wrote my own bindings.