# Manage non pip dependencies with poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry, zbar

We are develop our projects with poetry. In one of which we implement qr-code decoding. As the [pip package site](https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/) states `zbar` needs to be installed on the system.

Is it somehow possible that poetry/pip installs the `zbar` dependency, while installing our package?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. `poetry` is essentially a wrapper of `pip` and can only manage Python dependencies from PyPi.

You could consider something like `Nix` for this use case: https://github.com/NixOS/nix#nix

Or you could consider a `Makefile` that runs the appropriate `brew` or `apt-get`-equivalent based on the operating system.

Comment: Sounds like the `Makefile` is the only correct approach for the project this question originated from, since it was started as multiplattform. As far as I remember I removed my zbar dependency and used something else. Is `pip` able to handle `Makefiles` if I publish my package?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your follow-up question. You can configure your package to run arbitrary code on install like this https://github.com/KyleKing/not-on-pypi/blob/47c2e91cc676b9d6634e2387944d5fb9d4eb5495/setup.py#L40-L65, which can be combined with Makefiles like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45349660/3219667. There are a number of packages that rely on install scripts

Comment: Typically, the Makefile would be just for developers working on the package, like from this Python package template: https://github.com/TezRomacH/python-package-template (then seen: `{{ cookiecutter.project_name.lower().replace(' ', '_').replace('-', '_') }}/Makefile`)

Comment: This is the thing yes. I did not worked completely through your examples but seems going into right direction. So yes to concrete my follow-up question: So since I publish with package with poetry I wandered how to inform `pip` with `poetry` that a dependency like `zbar` needs to be installed. The audience of my package is visual datasience, which is in my experience not always that techsafe, so I wanted the install process kind of easy.

Comment: Oh, I see. I haven't tested it, but I think you can use [the "scripts" section for poetry to run the post-install logic](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts)