# Generating files for sdist

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm looking for a way to generate and include a file into the package created by `sdist`/`wheel`.

Is there some way to hook into the process to create a new file that will be picked up during the build.

Answer (score 1):

To build a file during `build` phase override `cmdclass`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43728788/7976758:

```
import distutils.command.build

# Override build command
class BuildCommand(distutils.command.build.build):

    def run(self):
        # Run the original build command
        distutils.command.build.build.run(self)
        # Custom build stuff goes here

# Replace the build command with ours
setup(...,
      cmdclass={"build": BuildCommand})
```

To include a non-code file in a `sdist` list in in `MANIFEST` or `MANIFEST.in`. See https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute

To include a non-code file in a `wheel` list it as `package_data` in your `setup.py`. See https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data:

```
setup(...,
      packages=['mypkg'],
      package_data={'mypkg': ['*.dat']},
      )
```