# How do I specify the build directory when building Python wheel packages?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel

I'm building a simple wheel package using `python setup.py bdist_wheel`.

This will build the package first in the directory `./build`. How can I customize that location?

For the `setup.py bdist` command there appears to be an argument `--bdist-base` but not so for `bdist_wheel`, I think.

Comment: I think it's impossible from the command line: `bdist_wheel` doesn't accept option `--build-base`. Perhaps it's possible with a [custom build class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43728788/7976758) (found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+custom+build+command): override `build` and set `self.build_base` before calling parent's `run()`.