# Is there a way to run custom commands before building with setuptools

Tags: python, deployment, setuptools, python-packaging

In my project i have a custom script that updates some python files that are imported within my python package.
Therefore it is importend to run this script before building the package.

Is there a way to do this within the regular setup.py file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+custom+build+command

Comment: Esp. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43728788/7976758 Run your custom build script before calling parent build.