# Python setuptools' "setup.py install" does not automatically call build?

Tags: python, setuptools

I am trying to package a Python 3.6 project which additionally requires compiling CPP code. My test setup.py file currently looks like this:

```
print("Hello world from setup.py")
from distutils.command.build import build
from setuptools import setup

class TestBuild(build):
    def run(self):
        print("Hello world from TestBuild")    

setup(
    name="Test",
    cmdclass={
        'build': TestBuild,
    },    
)
```

The idea here is to place the CPP-compiling code inside **TestBuild.** When I run **python setup.py build** it seems to work well:

```
> python setup.py build
Hello world from setup.py
running build
Hello world from TestBuild
```

However, running **python setup.py install** does not seem to run the build step at all:

```
> python setup.py install
Hello world from setup.py
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing Test.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to Test.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to Test.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'Test.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'Test.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
warning: install_lib: 'build/lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install

creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying Test.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying Test.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying Test.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying Test.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/Test-0.0.0-py3.5.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing Test-0.0.0-py3.5.egg
```

My questions:

1. Does the **install** command automatically invokes the **build** command?
2. If it does, what did I do wrong? If it does not, how can I ensure the **build** command runs?
3. Where can I find detailed description of the install process? I tried to dig inside the setuptools documentation and did not find anything like this.

Comment: The `build` command won't run because you haven't specified any source files to include in the egg, neither via `packages` nor via `python_modules` nor via `extensions` for C/C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

> - Does the install command automatically invokes the build command?

Yes but it doesn't run `python setup.py build` — it calls the
corresponding code right inside one process hence you never see the
second print. If you really need to print it you have to override `setuptools` commands with [custom classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11332078/7976758); create such classes for `build`, `bdist_egg` and `install` commands.

> - Where can I find detailed description of the install process? I tried to dig inside the setuptools documentation and did not find anything like this.

I'm afraid [`distutils`](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/distutils) and [`setuptools`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools) source code is the only authoritative reference.

[`bdist_egg`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/510c3c64bd32e7c3870001e5e7a56ca5e387e797/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py#L161) doesn't run `build` directly; it runs `egg_info`, `build_clib` and `install_lib`. [`install_lib`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/510c3c64bd32e7c3870001e5e7a56ca5e387e797/setuptools/command/install_lib.py#L10) calls [`distutils.build`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3f4d90d4d72921f16babd3f52d7df804916af224/Lib/distutils/command/install_lib.py#L102) which runs `build_py` and `build_ext`. So it seems you have to override `build_py`, not `build`.

Comment: I think that I've done the custom class thing - isn't it what I do in the attached code? Thanks!

Comment: This is clearly not true and I don't think it has been in past versions of setuptools.

Comment: @Peter What exactly is not true?

Comment: Passing a class inheriting from e.g. `build` to `cmdclass` will not result in that classes `run` method being called when running `python setup.py install`.

Comment: @Peter What about custom `build_py`?

Comment: @phd: Still no. maybe if you're running something other than `install` but that's what the OP was asking about. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your answer but I cannot produce a minimal working example.

Comment: @Peter I see. Thanks!